# Insert UIImage into table using InsertRows(at: with)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have an app that does direct messaging similar to instagram and others. Currently when a user enters text it immediately updates the UI.  Where I'm having trouble is when a user attempts to send an image.  It works on the backend, I'm seeing the image on the server and the reference in the database but it's not updating the UI with the image.  Instead it shows an empty row as if text was inputted.  My code is included below.

**Upload Image function**

```
func uploadImage(from imageView: UIImageView) {

    // save method of accessing ID of current user
    guard let id = user?["id"], let uuid = messages["uuid"] else {
        return
    }
    let recipient = messages["username"] as! String
    let rid = String(describing: messages["sender_id"]!)
    let sender = user!["username"] as! String
    puuid = UUID().uuidString

    // STEP 1. Declare URL, Request and Params
    // url we gonna access (API)
    let url = URL(string: "https://localhost/messagepost.php")!

    // declaring reqeust with further configs
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    // POST - safest method of passing data to the server
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    // values to be sent to the server under keys (e.g. ID, TYPE)
    let params = ["sender_id": id, "uuid": uuid, "sender": sender, "recipient_id": rid, "recipient": recipient, "puuid": puuid]

    // MIME Boundary, Header
    let boundary = "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let param = ["puuid" : puuid]

    // if in the imageView is placeholder - send no picture to the server
    // Compressing image and converting image to 'Data' type
    var imageData = Data()

    if pictureImg.image != nil {
        imageData = pictureImg.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)!
    }

    // assigning full body to the request to be sent to the server
    request.httpBody = Helper().body(with: params, filename: "\(param).jpg", filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: imageData, boundary: boundary) as Data

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            // error occured
            if error != nil {
                Helper().showAlert(title: "Server Error", message: error!.localizedDescription, in: self)
                return
            }


            do {

                // save mode of casting any data
                guard let data = data else {
                    Helper().showAlert(title: "Data Error", message: error!.localizedDescription, in: self)
                    return
                }

                // fetching JSON generated by the server - php file
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary

                // save method of accessing json constant
                guard let parsedJSON = json else {
                    return
                }

                // uploaded successfully
                if parsedJSON["status"] as! String == "200" {

                } else {

                    // show the error message in AlertView
                    if parsedJSON["message"] != nil {
                        let message = parsedJSON["message"] as! String
                        Helper().showAlert(title: "Error", message: message, in: self)
                    }

                }

            } catch {
                Helper().showAlert(title: "JSON Error", message: error.localizedDescription, in: self)
            }

        }
    }.resume()

    hhmessages.insert([pictureImg.image: imageData] as AnyObject, at: hhmessages.endIndex)

     let indexPath = IndexPath(row: hhmessages.count - 1, section: 0)

     tableView.beginUpdates()
     tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

     tableView.endUpdates()

     tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
}
```

**Upload text function**

```
func uploadPost() {
    // validating vars before sending to the server
    guard let user_id = user?["id"] as? String, let sender = user!["username"] as? String, let avaPath = user?["ava"] as? String
        else {

            // converting url string to the valid URL
            if let url = URL(string: user?["ava"] as! String) {

                // downloading all data from the URL
                guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
                    return
                }

                // converting donwloaded data to the image
                guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
                    return
                }

                // assigning image to the global var
                let currentUser_ava = image
                let ava = currentUser_ava
            }

            return
    }

    let messagetext = replyTxt.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let avame = user!["ava"]
    let postimage = pictureImg.image

    let recipientfe = messages["recipient"]
    let uuidfe = messages["uuid"] as! String

    hhmessages.insert(["messagetext": messagetext] as AnyObject, at: hhmessages.endIndex)
    print(user?["ava"])

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: hhmessages.count - 1, section: 0)

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

    tableView.endUpdates()

    tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)

    replyTxt.text = ""

    let recipient = messages["username"] as! String

    let rid = String(describing: messages["sender_id"]!)
    let uuid = messages["uuid"] as! String

    puuid = UUID().uuidString


    // prepare request
    let url = URL(string: "https://localhost/messagepost.php")!
    let body = "sender_id=\(user_id)&sender=\(sender)&text=\(messagetext)&recipient_id=\(rid)&recipient=\(recipient)&uuid=\(uuidfe)&puuid=\(puuid)"

            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)

        // send request
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                // error happened
                if error != nil {
                    Helper().showAlert(title: "Server Error", message: error!.localizedDescription, in: self)
                    return
                }

                do {
                    // converting received data from the server into json format
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary

                    // safe mode of casting json
                    guard let parsedJSON = json else {
                        return
                    }

                    // if the status of JSON is 200 - success
                    if parsedJSON["status"] as! String == "200" {

                        // comment is inserted
                        print(parsedJSON)

                    } else {
                        Helper().showAlert(title: "400", message: parsedJSON["message"] as! String, in: self)
                        return
                    }

                // json error
                } catch {
                    Helper().showAlert(title: "JSON Error", message: error.localizedDescription, in: self)
                    return
                }

            }
        }.resume()

    }
```

**Table View Code**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return hhmessages.count }

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
return 1
 }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let colorSmoothGray = UIColor(red: 229/255, green: 229/255, blue: 234/255, alpha: 1)
    let colorBrandBlue = UIColor(red: 148 / 255, green: 33 / 255, blue: 147 / 255, alpha: 1)
let pictureURL = hhmessages[indexPath.row]["uploadpath"] as? String

// no picture in the post
if pictureURL?.isEmpty == true {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ConversationCell
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi));

    isLoading = true

    let hhpost = hhmessages[indexPath.row]
    let smimages = hhpost["path"] as? UIImage
    let text = hhmessages[indexPath.row]["messagetext"] as! String
    cell.messageLbl.text = text
    cell.smavaImg.image = smimages

        cell.messageLbl.textAlignment = .right
        cell.messageLbl.backgroundColor = colorSmoothGray
        cell.messageLbl.textColor = .black
        cell.messageLbl.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.body)
        cell.messageLbl.font?.withSize(25)
        cell.messageLbl.clipsToBounds = true
          // get main queue to this block of code to communicate back
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
    cell.messageLbl.sizeToFit()
    tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi)
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)

}
    return cell
} else {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PicCell", for: indexPath) as! PicConversationCell
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi));

    cell.smavaImg.image = smimages
    //if let message = messageData {
    for i in 0 ..< self.incoming.count {
        // Confiture the constraints for cell
        if self.incoming[indexPath.row] == 1 {
                             // Constraints
           cell.lefBubbleConstraint.isActive = true
            cell.rightBubbleConstraint.isActive = false
            if cell.postpictureImg.image == nil {
                cell.postpictureImg.backgroundColor = colorwhite
                cell.postpictureImg.clipsToBounds = true

            }
            else {
                cell.postpictureImg.backgroundColor = .clear
                cell.postpictureImg.clipsToBounds = true

            }

        }
        else if self.incoming[indexPath.row] == 0 {


            // Constraints
            cell.lefBubbleConstraint.isActive = false
            cell.rightBubbleConstraint.isActive = true
            if cell.postpictureImg.image == nil {
                cell.postpictureImg.backgroundColor = colorwhite
                cell.postpictureImg.clipsToBounds = true

            }
            else {
                cell.postpictureImg.backgroundColor = .clear
                cell.postpictureImg.clipsToBounds = true

            }

        }

    // pictures logic
    let pictureString = hhmessages[indexPath.row]["uploadpath"] as? String
    let pictureURL = URL(string: pictureString!)!

    // if there are still pictures to be loaded
    if hhmessages.count != pictures.count {

        URLSession(configuration: .default).dataTask(with: pictureURL) { (data, response, error) in
                              // downloaded
            if let image = UIImage(data: data!) {

                self.pictures.append(image)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.postpictureImg.image = image
                }
            }

            }.resume()

        // cached picture
    } else {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.postpictureImg.image = self.pictures[indexPath.row]
        }
    }

    }

    return cell

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you get the image for the cell in the cellForRowAt datasource function. you get it as a value for "uploadpath" key. While you don't use that key when you insert the image.

> Therefore pictureURL?.isEmpty == true will always be true in this
>   case.

I would suggest that you use same key to insert the image. something like:

```
hhmessages.insert(["uploadpath": pictureImg.image] as AnyObject, at: hhmessages.endIndex)
```

Then when you get it in cellForRowAt. you need to check for type:

```
if pictureURL.isEmpty {
    //text
} else {
    //image
    if pictureURL is UIImage {
       //uiimage
    } else {
       //url
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @hasan I'm slightly confused on the revision to the conditional statement.  The image will always be uploaded a URL.  What are you suggesting should go there?

Comment: I tried it using "uploadpath": pictureImg.image and it's still not updating the UI with the image.  Any other thoughts? I truly appreciate the assistance.

Comment: you are uploading an image then u wanna insert it to ur tableview without fetching the data again from server. therefore when u finish upload u don't have the url for that uploaded image. so you actually inserting the image itself in the hhmessage. u don't have the url anyway. so no its not always urls in ur hhmessage

Comment: no other thoughts. that is the thought of ur problem.

Comment: hhmessages.insert([pictureImg.image: imageData] as AnyObject, at: hhmessages.endIndex) this line u insert the image in a strange way. I suggested this: ["uploadpath": pictureImg.image]. so you can fetch it with the key later in cellForRowAt.

Comment: Thanks Hasan, that's what I tried as well but I'm still not getting it to show immediately like the text.

Comment: therefore, you have url some times and UIImage some times. you need to check the type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204276/discussion-between-techgirl-and-hasan).